# Contact form redirects to PHP error page

Tags: php, html, email

I'm trying to to submit my HTML form to the PHP script (which works fine) but then the PHP should send it to an email. Instead it ends up on an error page. So I think the HTML code is not the problem, there must be an error in the PHP. Can anyone help me to fix this error?

**Update: Now there are no more errors, but it redirects me to a blank site..**

Updated HTML:

```
<form method="post" name="myform" action="form-to-email.php" id="myform">
      <div class="form-group col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1"> <!-- Date input -->
        <label class="control-label" for="date1">Date of arrival</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="date" name="date1" placeholder="MM/DD/YYY" type="text"/>
      </div>
       <div class="form-group col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1"> <!-- Date input -->
         <label class="control-label" for="date2">Date of departure</label>
         <input class="form-control" id="date2" name="date2" placeholder="MM/DD/YYY" type="text"/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
    <label for="adults">Adults</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="adults">
        <option>0</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>
        <option>7</option>
        <option>8</option>
      </select>
  </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
    <label for="children">Children (under 14 years)</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="children">
         <option>0</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>


      </select>
  </div><br><br>
  <p class="location text-center col-xs-12"> Please enter your name and address:</p>
   <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="title">
         <option>Mr.</option>
        <option>Mrs.</option>

      </select>
  </div>
     <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
    <label for="lastname">First name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname">
  </div>
   <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
    <label for="lastname">Last name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" name="lastname">
  </div>
   <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-3">
    <label for="lastname">Adress </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="adress" name="adress">
  </div>
   <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1">
    <label for="lastname">N°</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="n°" name="n°">
  </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-3">
    <label for="lastname">City </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" name="city">
  </div>
   <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1">
    <label for="zip">ZIP</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="zip" name="zip">
  </div>
   <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
    <label for="country">Country</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="country" name="country">
  </div>
     <p class="location text-center col-xs-12"> Please enter your contact details:</p>
      <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
    <label for="email">E-mail</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">
  </div>
     <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
       <label for="mobile">Mobile number</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobile" name="mobile">
  </div> <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
       <label for="comments">Comments</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="comments" name="comments" style="height: 100px;">
  </div>
      <div class="form-group"> <!-- Submit button -->
        <button class="btn btn-primary col-sm-offset-5" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
     </form>
```

Updated PHP:

```
   <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "someones@email.com";
    $email_subject = "Booking request";

    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }


    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['date1']) ||
        !isset($_POST['date2']) ||
        !isset($_POST['adults']) ||
        !isset($_POST['children']) ||
        !isset($_POST['title']) ||
        !isset($_POST['firstname']) ||
        !isset($_POST['lastname']) ||
        !isset($_POST['adress']) ||
        !isset($_POST['n°']) ||
        !isset($_POST['city']) ||
        !isset($_POST['zip']) ||
        !isset($_POST['country']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['mobile'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }



    $date1 = $_POST['date1']; // required
    $date2 = $_POST['date2']; // required
    $adults = $_POST['adults']; // required
    $children = $_POST['children']; // required
    $title = $_POST['title']; // required
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname']; // required
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname']; // required
    $adress = $_POST['adress']; // required
    $n° = $_POST['n°']; // required
    $city = $_POST['city']; // required
    $zip = $_POST['zip']; // required
    $country = $_POST['country']; // required
    $email = $_POST['email']; // required
    $mobile = $_POST['mobile']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // not required


    $error_message = "Please fill all required fields.";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$firstname)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$lastname)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";


    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }



    $email_message .= "Date of Arrival: ".clean_string($date1)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Date of Departure: ".clean_string($date2)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Adults: ".clean_string($adults)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Children: ".clean_string($children)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Title: ".clean_string($title)."\n";
    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($firstname)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($lastname)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Adress: ".clean_string($adress)."\n";
    $email_message .= "N°: ".clean_string($n°)."\n";
    $email_message .= "City: ".clean_string($city)."\n";
    $email_message .= "ZIP: ".clean_string($zip)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Country: ".clean_string($country)."\n \n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Mobile: ".clean_string($mobile)."\n";

// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($email, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 
header('Location: thank-you.html'); 

?>

<!-- include your own success html here -->



<?php
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: There is a syntax error in code ` died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');` it should be ` die('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');`

Comment: @NileshDaladra if you notice, the OP has made that a custom function, 8th line down.

Comment: If it's a php error as you say check the logs and post what you see in the log file.

Comment: Ohhh...i didn't noticed ;)

Comment: might be  $n° one affects

Comment: Just use `count()` instead of all the `isset()` so do `if(count($_POST) != 15) {` The count being how many fields are set in the post

Comment: At the last line after `mail()` function you can put it under if condition and echo html message then redirect to home page.Also check your email parameters if you are getting any blank values.

Comment: "in the last row of the php it says there is an unexpected end." That means there's at least one syntax error which you need to find and fix. This is the first one: `$headers = 'From: '.$email". \r\n".` You put the string-concatenation dot inside the string by mistake. `$headers = 'From: '.$email." \r\n".` should fix it. There are others too, just find them and fix them. The error message should tell you roughly where in the code to look (line number).

Comment: Thank you @ADyson for your comment, now I made sure that there are no errors, and now it doesn't redirect me to an error page but it gets stuck on a blank page.

Comment: your form-to-email.php is probably not detecing the $_POST["submit"] because you don't have an input type submit. The button element isn't sending as a "submit" for the form. Try adding this attribute to the button element: form="myform"

Comment: nvm my comment dangit... didn't see the type=submit off the scroll

Comment: @Liquidchrome i too thought this as a same you posted, he has to change the button attribute to input type submit in order to work or as per your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
```

returns `false` when the form is posted back because, although you have a button with `name="submit"`, it doesn't have a `value` attribute. Therefore the "submit" variable is empty when you submit the form, causing `isset` to return false.

Simply add

```
value="submit"
```

to your button, e.g.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary col-sm-offset-5" name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
```

N.B. There's no requirement for `value` to have any specific content. `value="x"` would work just as well - all the code tests for is the existence of a value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it still doesn't work, it gets stuck on a blank page. I tried to submit the form on my local server, is that wrong?

Comment: Or do i need to install a mail server on my localhost in order to get an email?

Comment: as long as you're using it at localhost and PHP is actually installed etc the code should run. It may or may not actually send the email, depending how the server is configured, but you should at least get some output on screen. Is it redirecting you to `thank-you.html`? Or stopping before that? If you want to trace the flow of execution you could put some `echo` or `var_dump` statements into the code temporarily to see where it gets up to (and comment out the redirect header as well, so you don't get taken to another page before it can show you any output).

Comment: P.S. You can check if the mail was sent by PHP (note that this is _not_ the same as the mail being _received_, as lots of other things can interfere with that) by doing `$success = mail($email, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); echo "result of mail function:"; var_dump($success); die();` You should get true or false, if the code is actually reaching that point.